# How to implement a feature such that only followers can see post if the post is followers only?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to implement a feature in my blog app where users can make the post "followers-only". If it is followers-only then only followers can see the post and if not then everyone can see it. At the moment I made a solution but I don't if it is efficient way like doing this in security rules of my database. I have no idea writing a function in database rules.

I tried to implement this feature by addig a rule in my source code itself with an `if-else` statement.

```dart
Future _checkFollowing() async {
    List<DocumentSnapshot> _checkFollow = [];
    Query q = Firestore.instance
        .collection('user')
        .document(ownerId)
        .collection('followers')
        .where('profileId', isEqualTo: uid);

    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await q.getDocuments();
    _checkFollow = querySnapshot.documents;
    if (_checkFollow.length == 1) {
      setState(() {
        isFollowing = true;
      });
    } else if (_checkFollow.length == 0) {
      setState(() {
        isFollowing = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

```dart
if (followersOnlyPost) {
   if (isFollowing) {
      return buildPost();
    } else if (!isFollowing) {
      return null;
    }
 } else if (!followersOnlyPost) {
    return buildPost();     
 }
```

I have a `followers` subcollection to every user in database.
A post collection in which in each post there is a `followers-only` boolean field.
This is how I craete a post document

```dart
Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) {
      var reference = Firestore.instance.collection('all_posts');

      reference.add({
        'timestamp': DateTime.now(),
        'likes': {},
        'followersOnly': false,
        'bookmarks': {},
        'likesCount': 0,
        'ownerId': uid,
      }).then((DocumentReference doc) {
        String docId = doc.documentID;
        reference.document(docId).updateData({"postId": docId});});
```

My code does what I wanted but for everypost the function `_checkFollowing` is called and as a result it counts as 1 read in evry post. 
As there will be many post in the feed, it will result in lots of read count.

Also I want to implement block feature, but I haven't worked on that because I have no I idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is check who the user is following when the app is loaded (if there is an internet connection) and store it in a sqlite database. Then when it checks if the post is "Followers Only" you can check from the sqlite database locally, without having to call the database. This method will mean you will only get one database call every time the app is opened.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but one more thing that came to my mind is that if I load all the following, that will also be a problem if the user is following many of them, which in result will also increase read count. :(

Comment: In my opinion loading all of the user's followings should only count as one single read. But I don't know how Firestore works so it may not be the case, it may count every single user as a database call.